# Cluttered, uninterpretable output from PytagCloud in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, tag-cloud, word-cloud

I am trying to create a tag cloud in python using `pytagcloud` and I am using the following code to generate it:

```
from pytagcloud import create_tag_image, make_tags
from pytagcloud.lang.counter import get_tag_counts

with open("fileName.txt") as file:
  Data1 = file.read().lower()
  Data = Data1.split()

Data = "%s " * len(Data) % tuple(Data)
tags = make_tags(get_tag_counts(Data), maxsize=150)

create_tag_image(tags, 'cloud_large.png', size=(1200, 800))
```

The code runs without errors (takes a while though) but the output file that it generates is quite cluttered and not easy to read. Here's the output file:

[image: Tag Cloud]

Why am I getting this weird unreadable matrix-like clutter in the center? How can I get rid of it?
The tag cloud doesn't appear to be in the center of the file, how can that be done?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

P.S. - I am using Python 2.7

Answer (score 3):

if it still relevant,
what i did to solve this was to add value to minsize parameter and filter out all the smallest words (which probably appears once in the text). i guess it happens because of explosion in the number of words.

my code looks like:

```
tags = make_tags(get_tag_counts(MY_TEXT), maxsize=120, minsize=5)
tags = [a for a in tags if a['size'] > 7]
create_tag_image(tags, 'images/cloud_large.png', size=(900, 600), fontname='Reenie Beanie', background=(0,0,0))
```

and the result:
[image]

i chose the values empirically.